# Android:Draw image in the center of another image

Tags: android, image

I have one image `image 1` and one is coming from server that is `image 2` i am trying to draw second one just at the center of the first. as result i want single image like in pic . 
[image]

Comment: May this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634496/android-image-over-image

center the second image with margin.

Comment: @viperbone what i want is a single image after combining both images

Comment: see my answer below. Is it what you looking for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

The `backgroundBitmap` variable would be your `image1` and the `bitmapToDrawInTheCenter` would be your `image2`.

```
public void centerImageInOtherImage()
{
    Bitmap backgroundBitmap        = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap bitmapToDrawInTheCenter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    
    Bitmap resultingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroundBitmap.getWidth(), backgroundBitmap.getHeight(), backgroundBitmap.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDrawInTheCenter, (backgroundBitmap.getWidth() - bitmapToDrawInTheCenter.getWidth()) / 2, (backgroundBitmap.getHeight() - bitmapToDrawInTheCenter.getHeight()) / 2, new Paint());
    
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    image.setImageBitmap(resultingBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy : [Draw text/Image on another Image in Android](http://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/06/10/writing-text-pasting-image-on-bitmap-image-programatically/)

Drawing images over each other is fairly simple with Canvas. Canvas basically acts as the drawing board to draw text/Image. You just need to construct a canvas with the first Image and then draw the second Image at the center as shown below

```
/* This ImageOne will be used as the canvas to draw an another image over it. Hence we make it mutable using the copy API
as shown below
*/
      Bitmap imageOne = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imageOne).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
      // Decoding the image two resource into a Bitmap
      Bitmap imageTwo= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imageTwo);
      // Here we construct the canvas with the specified bitmap to draw onto
      Canvas canvas=new Canvas(imageOne);

/*Here we draw the image two on the canvas using the drawBitmap API.
drawBitmap takes in four parameters
1 . The Bitmap to draw
2.  X co-ordinate to draw from
3.  Y co ordinate to draw from
4.  Paint object to define style
*/
      canvas.drawBitmap(imageTwo,(imageOne.getWidth())/2,(imageOne.getHeight())/2,new Paint());

      imageView.setImageBitmap(imageOne);
```