# Add an image as background and put other images on top of it

Tags: java, android, image, background

I am creating an image by using Canvas- and Bitmap class. I want to set it as a background for the user. Then I want to add some more images on top of it.

this is the code for image that is supposed to be as background.

```
ImageView imgMap1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMap1);
imgMap1.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 500, 500)));
```

and this is the code to make it as background:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nn);
this.setContentView(ll);
```

The Problem here is: When I set it as background, I can't see the other photo anymore.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

The other Images are added in the Layout. they are movable by finger touch. user can reposition them by finger.

```
ImageView i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image1);
    ImageView i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image2);
```

Comment: Can you post more code about how the other image is added?

Comment: You could draw the second image over the first image. Have a look at my answer how you can achieve this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330220/androiddraw-image-in-the-center-of-another-image/12332941#12332941

Comment: Thanks to your answer. The code is added. 

I have two possibility. I can add them in the layout, Or I can add them in the java code.

Which one will work?

Comment: @viperbone: I saw your code, but this is an imageview and this is movable by using OnDragListener. 
Do u have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

The layout is built from the top down in your XML file, or in the order you add elements in code.  It sounds like your other images is being added to the layout first, either as a higher-up element in the XML file, or earlier in your code. You'll need to add the other code as context for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that you can directly set `Bitmap` as your `ImageView`'s content using `setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)`[See the Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

Then let talk about your question.

First, create your own class extends the `View`;
Second, load background image and overlay image using Bitmap
Third, invoke `onTouch` event, so that the `onDraw` method will automatically redraw the overlay image using the coordinates returned by `onTouch`

Something like:

```
public class dragndrop extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // using this to load your background image
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;  // this is not a must       
    bmBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opt);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawView dv = new DrawView(dragndrop.this);
    setContentView(dv);
}


public class DrawView extends View {

    Point coordinate;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true); //necessary for getting the touch events
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // assume you have already load your background image as bitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmBackground, 0, 0, null);

    // assume bm is the overlay image you need to put on top,
        // the method here will draw the object with the coordinate you give
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, null);
    }



   // events when touching the screen
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

        int x = (int)event.getX(); 
        int y = (int)event.getY(); 

        switch (eventaction ) { 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        // add code here to determine the point user touched is within the object or not

                    break;
                }
              }

             break; 


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch 'n' drag 

            // pass the touch point to your object
            coordinate.x = x;
            coordinate.y = y;

            break; 

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

             break; 
        } 
        // redraw the canvas
        invalidate(); 
        return true; 

    }


}


}
```

This is my own snippet, please edit before use, and please let me know when your question is resolved.

Comment: This solution is a little different from my coding, So I have no idea about it. I will try it and will report the result.