# How to add a date/time for a image using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, cordova

Is it possible to add a date/time to an image which is taken from Android/iOS/Windows Phone/Blackberry using phonegap.

Our apps is used to add a date for every image which taken from our app, so whenever i am taking a picture form my app using phonegap, i want to add a date for that image on the fly. Just want to know this is possible in phonegap for Android/WP7/iOS/Blackberry.

In phonegap if we cant acheive, atleast it is possible to acheieve in native for all platforms(android, WP7, iOS, Blackberry).

Find the attached image with caption at below right corner. Kindly give a suggestion in which way we acheive this via native in all platform or we can do in phonegap itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <style>
    .image {
        position:relative;
    }
    .image .text {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:10px;
        right:540px;
        width:300px;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <tr>
    <div class="image">
      <img alt="" src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/img/class-header-css3.jpg" />
      <div class="text">
        <p>21/8/13</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </tr>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think your not understand my question, i am asking this kind of image with date on the fly while shoot a image from a phone. Not to append to an existing image.

Comment: you can't you must require custom camera plugin for this all platform Android/iOS/Windows Phone/Blackberry

Comment: You mean we can do with custom camera plugin in native code ??? What is custom camera plugin??? Please share some reference if you have for all platforms. Its helps me lot...

Comment: there is not in build plugin for custom camera you need to develop by your self for every platform or you can update the camera plugin of phonegap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154888/how-to-make-a-single-image-of-current-date-as-text-and-camera-captured-image-in