# Android - How to set onClick listener for a portion of an ImageButton

Tags: android, image, uiimageview, preview, event-listener

I have an application with an `ImageButton` that when clicked triggers a `method`. Now my problem is that I want a portion of that same `ImageButton` that when clicked calls a different `method`. I would like to set the bottom right corner to call a different method than the one being called when clicking the `ImageButton`.

The idea is that clicking the image button triggers a save to a `database`, but the clicking on the corner should display a preview of the image.

Any help on how this can be achieved will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to do this? Why not just use two different buttons? That should be more clear to the users

Comment: This post answers to my questio:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634496/android-image-over-image/3634520#3634520?s=94e1a99f-1057-4a97-9d5c-2c71b137b6e5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out [Android ImageLayout](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout)... you could use an ImageLayout as an imagebutton. On the specified points/corners (rectHint), you could place a different clicklistener, which executes a different method.

I didnt try, but it "should" solve your problem.