# How make mark icon on picture Android?

Tags: android, image

[image: Make mark icon Best Saler]

I have a mark icon Best Saler and i don't have ideal for that.
please help me.Thank for watching!

Comment: Are you asking a programming site to make you an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapOverlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, int left, int top) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(),  bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);    
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, left, top, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}


//using getBitmapOverlay, u need read big image ->myBitmap
//read bigSale image -> nextBitmap
//u can change left, top
myBitmap = getBitmapOverlay(myBitmap, nextBitmap, 0, 0));
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Thank for your support!
Best Saler icon is displayed but it in image, how to move icon to left of parent layout (have border)

Comment: In your case, try to use Layout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634496/android-image-over-image

Comment: it working for me.thanks!
Mình làm được rồi, cảm ơn bạn nhiều nha.